# How to execute process with mmap-ed memory as stdin and another mmap-ed memory as stdout?

Tags: c++, linux, stdout, stdin, mmap

It is possible in Linux execute process with mmap-ed memory as stdin and another mmap-ed memory as stdout, so parent program can preallocate memory for stdin, write necessary data, execute program and read their output from memory not using temporary files or pipes?

I can create shared memory object, set it size with 'ftruncate' and map it. Thus i have file descriptor, but what next? How can i pass it to child process invoked by std::system or exec.

```
int fd = shm_open( "/my_stdin", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0 );

size_t size = 100;
ftruncate( fd, size )

char * p_shm = (char *)mmap( 0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );

...?
```

Comment: Do you mean pass the file descriptor as standard input? Can you explain why you suspect that doing exactly the same thing with this file descriptor as with any other file descriptor, namely `dup2()`ing it to 0, will not work?

Comment: @Sam, I'am not so familiar with Linux programming, but yes, it was such simple just using dup2. It works how i expected for stdin and stdout.
Thank you!

Comment: ...Isn't this just a pipe with a mmap on the source side?

Comment: May be this just a pipe, but i don't need a pipe.